# contains() ,indexOf() are not matching the value anytime while passing variable

Tags: javascript

The `indexOf` is giving for hardcoded value for example `msgs.indexOf("Program")` but not for the given variable.
Here `msgs` is an array object containing multiple strings and `str[temp][1]` is a string which exist in `msgs`. but it is not giving `true` as output.

```
 if ((msgs.indexOf(str[temp][1])) != -1) {
     document.getElementById("jsmatch").innerHTML = "true";
     Counter++;
     break;
 } else {
     document.getElementById("jsmatch").innerHTML = "false";
     break;
 }
```

Comment: this code is written in javascript and passed in a function called in body tag. the file in which it is written is a xsl file,temp is a variable which works like a counter i , j we generally use.

Comment: Where's the code for the `str[][]`? Also, the `msgs`.

Comment: Interpreters don't lie. If `indexOf` returns -1, then the string does NOT exist in the array. Add `console.log` all over the place and look what it says.

Comment: indexOf is giving what exactly? I'm having trouble making sense of your question.

Comment: Please provide a [self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) with all relevant code. Obviously `str[temp][1]` is not an item in `msgs`…

Comment: @thg435:where should I add consol.log?

Comment: Before the `if` statement you could add `console.log(temp+"/"+str[temp][1])` and then check what you get on the Javascript console

Comment: Example:str1[temp]=infozzzzzthe string is working;
 str[temp]=str1[temp].split('zzzzz'); ,here str[temp][1] will contain "the string is working";

Comment: and what's the value of `msgs`...?

Answer (score 0):

when you call indexOf on an array with an argument, it returns the index of that argument in that array or -1 if that argument is not contained in that array.